# Gethbase processor from 1 table Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

```
gethbase >> execute_script
```

Hello, I have problem with backpressure object threshold when processing data from hbase to executing script with Jython. If just 1 processor is executed, my queue is always full, because the first processor is faster than the second. I was making concurrent tasks of second processor from 1 to 3 or 4 but it makes new error message. Here:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OxNg.png)

Anyone here has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might actually increase your work a bit but I would highly recommend writing Groovy for your custom implementation as opposed to Python/Jython/JRuby.

A couple of reasons for that!

1. Groovy was built "for the JVM" and leverages/integrates with Java more cleanly
2. Jython is an implementation of Python for the JVM. There is a lot of back and forth which happen between Python and JVM which can substantially increase the overhead.

If you still prefer to go with Jython, there are still a couple of things that you can do!

- Use `InvokeScriptedProcessor (ISP)` instead of `ExecuteScript`. ISP is faster because it only loads the script once, then invokes methods on it, rather than ExecuteScript which evaluates the script each time.
- Use `ExecuteStreamCommand` with command-line Python instead. You won't have the flexibility of accessing attributes, processor state, etc. but if you're just transforming content you should find ExecuteStreamCommand with Python faster.
- No matter which language you choose, you can often improve performance if you use `session.get(int)` instead of `session.get()`. That way if there are a lot of flow files in the queue, you could call `session.get(1000)` or something, and process up to 1000 flow files per execution. If your script has a lot of overhead, you may find handling multiple flow files per execution can significantly improve performance.